# Get daily sales from a database

Tags: mysql, sql

With the help of this great community I get this solution to group the daily sales by 2 hours interval.

```
SELECT   SUBSTRING(DATE(o.date_purchased) + 
         INTERVAL (HOUR(o.date_purchased) -
         HOUR(o.date_purchased) MOD 2) HOUR , 12) AS time_purchased,
         ROUND(SUM(ot.value), 2) AS sales_today,
         COUNT(*) AS orders_today
FROM     orders AS o
JOIN     orders_total AS ot ON ot.orders_id = o.orders_id
WHERE    ot.class = 'ot_total'
AND      o.date_purchased >= CURRENT_DATE()
AND      o.date_purchased <  CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY DATE(o.date_purchased) +
         INTERVAL (HOUR(o.date_purchased) -
         HOUR(o.date_purchased) MOD 2) HOUR
```

How do I change this query to get the daily sales of every day of a month. Starting automatically with the first day and ending with the last day of the actual month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get daily sales of current month you can write your query as

```
SELECT   DATE(o.date_purchased)  AS date_purchased,
         ROUND(SUM(ot.value), 2) AS sales_per_day,
         COUNT(*) AS orders_today
FROM     orders AS o
JOIN     orders_total AS ot ON ot.orders_id = o.orders_id
WHERE    ot.class = 'ot_total'
AND      o.date_purchased >= LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND      o.date_purchased <= LAST_DAY(NOW())
GROUP BY DATE(o.date_purchased)
```

Comment: Great, nearly perfect, but with this solution I get the 31st march on the result.

Comment: @user1286819 see my updated answer i have changed my condition to `LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY` this will surely give you the results from current month

Comment: Many. many thanks. It works fantastic. With your solution I could save nearly 30 mysql queries.